# Hibernate "could not execute query" Exception!

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, tomcat, struts

```
exception 
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
    org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:286)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)


root cause 
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
    org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:91)
    org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:79)
    org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2153)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2029)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2024)
    org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:369)
    org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:300)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:153)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1127)
    org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:79)
    org.cosmosociety.actions.BlogAction.execute(BlogAction.java:35)
```

My environment is postgre + tomcat + hibernate 3 + struts 1.x. I am going to take a look at hibernate 3 source code later. I will update everybody if I find the solution.

Comment: Posting the actual query here would help diagnosing the problem. Also, why is this community wiki?

Comment: I am sorry about the wiki thing. However, I could not get the sql command, because that's already in the hosting server. The application works fine with my local machine. It just do not work for the hosting server. :(

Comment: Could you include your hibernate query, or your hibernate criteria, and perhaps some of the code leading up to this exception? It would help us understand the problem if we could see the code that created the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked your permissions? If it is working locally and not on your hosting, you may have credentials issue.

Comment: This is a great point. However, in my case, it does not seem to apply. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Check for the differences between the 'hosting server' and your local machine.

Especially do a diff on the two schemas

For further debugging:

- Activate SQL-Logging, so you get the offending sql-statement. If you can't do it globally do it programmatically before the command causing the exception and deactivate it afterwards.
- Execute the sql statement on your machine and on the 'hosting server'
- Assuming you get an exception on the hosting server, but still don't see the reason, simplify the sql statement step by step, until you find the problematic piece, which in turn should identify the problem pretty well.

Comment: Thanks, I will check through these points and update everybody here:)

Answer (score 0):

what your writing query you not placed here?

In before i am also getting the same type of error by using the hibernate.

In my application i am doing some mistake like my table column name i am giving wrong.

When i am correcting the table column name that all are displayed successfully.

you also check your all column names in dbtable and your giving property names in java classes.